# Doesn't work "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM..." in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

My function should return number of rows with email like '$email'. But whey return 0 all the time, although in database i have rows with email like I insert in variable '$email'. What could be the reason?

```
function checkMail($email){     
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email='$email'";       
    return mysql_query($sql);   
}
```

Comment: You say `like`... but you use `=`. Stop using mysql, the functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO, and either pass a connection resource into the function or acquire it globally.

Comment: change the return to  `return mysql_query($sql) or die("MySQL error for $sql:" . mysql_error());` It will show you an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning a result, you're returning a **query resource:**

```
function checkMail($email){     
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as emailCount FROM users WHERE email='$email'";       
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // show error if one happens
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

This will return an associative array containing your results (if it succeeds), and you should be able to access your count by:

```
$res = checkMail('your@email.com');
$count = $res['emailCount'];
```

> Side note:

`mysql` functions are deprecated, you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` syntax:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/2812842

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkMail($email){     
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email='$email'";       
  $resource=mysql_query($sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($resource);
  return $row[0];   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To fetch the count use:

```
mysql_query($sql)
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return($row[0]);
```

The funny thing is that mysql_query return 0, which indicates query fail. Check the corresponding error message with:

```
echo mysql_error();
```